# sending email with UTL_SMTP

Tags: oracle, email

I have a package in Oracle which sends email using UTL_SMTP. But when I run it in oracle version 19 , it dosn't work and i get this error:

ORA-20000: Failed to send mail due to the following error: ORA-29279: Permanenter SMTP-Fehler: 554 For explanation visit https://www.ionos.com/help/index.php?id=2425&ip=80.152.187.21&c=hd

anyone knows why this happens? it works fine in oracle version 11.

Comment: Did you grant in ACL-Settings?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but didn't work.

Comment: Maybe a firewall issue. Is the DB server able to connect to the SMTP server?